# UISearch is prefilled by default - Detect when text is entered and remove the default text

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have a UISearch bar that is prefilled with 'Current Location',however when the user starts typing I would like to remove the prefilled text and only show the text that the user is typing. I have tried this but cant seem to get it working:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    if ([self.searchBar.text isEqualToString:CURRENT_LOCATION]) {
        self.searchBar.text=@"";
    }
}
```

Comment: obviously, `searchText` isn't equal to `CURRENT_LOCATION` anymore after the text changed. Better use `-(BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use Folowing

- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
```